# Bash sorting list by keyword

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

I'm trying to write a bash script that takes an input stream and sorts lines containing a keyword to the top.

Starting point:

```
$ cat file
cat
dog
mouse
bird
cat and mouse
lorem
ipsum
```

Goal:

```
$ cat file | sort-by-keyword mouse
mouse
cat and mouse
cat
dog
bird
lorem
ipsum
```

I've tried to implement this using sort but failed. Is another tool/way I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

script file `sort-by-keyword`:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$(cat)"
echo "$input" | sed "/$1/p;d"
echo "$input" | sed "/$1/!p;d"
```

Usage:

```
chmod +x sort-by-keyword

cat file | ./sort-by-keyword mouse
```

Comment: Awesome, does exactly what I hoped for

Comment: Hey MichalH, do you know a way to loop over a list of keyword from a file and run the command for each of them too? That would solve the next step for me

Comment: You can do that in a for loop, have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521498/4270339.

Answer (score 1):

You can not sorting rest of the records. Based on input. please try

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /mouse/) {print} else {a[NR]=$0}} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}'
```

Demo:

```
$cat file.txt 
cat
dog
mouse
bird
cat and mouse
lorem
ipsum
$awk '{if ($0 ~ /mouse/) {print} else {a[NR]=$0}} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}' file.txt 
mouse
cat and mouse
bird
lorem
ipsum
cat
dog
$
```

Answer (score 1):

One dirty way to achieve it:

```
grep mouse file && grep -v mouse file
```